# ASP.NET.core swagger generate swagger file programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an asp.net core web api that I created from the wizard - and it's generated code like this:

```cs
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
    ...
```

And if I run it, I get a swagger url, and I can go to

```
https://localhost:7100/swagger/v1/swagger.yaml
```

and get a yaml file...  that's all good.

**The Question**

However, I need that yaml file in the CI/CD process for various reasons, so I want to get it dynamically after building, but starting a web server, calling it, and bringing it down has a lot of ways it can go wrong.  What I'd like to do is just make a command line option to get the swagger file that never starts something listening on http.  so I can just run "dotnet run myApi generate_swagger_yaml >swagger.yaml"   Something like:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if (args[0] == "generate_swagger_yaml")
   {
        var yamlFile = ....somehow get the swagger yaml file...
        Console.Writeline( yamlfile );
        return 0;
   }
   ...
```

but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my last answer, I've had to experiment more with Swashbuckle and Swagger generation and I've found the actual answer to your original question.

Once you create your builder:

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

You need to fetch the IServiceProvider from it and use it to resolve an instance of `ISwaggerProvider`.  With this, you can get the swagger document and render it to Json or Yaml.

```
var swaggerProvider = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
var swagger = swaggerProvider.GetSwagger("v1");
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
swagger.SerializeAsV3(new OpenApiYamlWriter(stringWriter));
var swaggerYaml = stringWriter.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(swaggerYaml);
```

Where "v1" should be the default name of your swagger doc which you can specify when setting it up like so:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerDoc("v7", null);
});
```

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817070/how-to-skip-exceptions-when-running-dotnet-swagger-tofile-using-swashbuckle-as can you please take a look at this question, do you have any idea how to solve that? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend *not* building this into your application directly.  Swashbuckle (the library which actually generates the swagger doc at runtime) offers a CLI tool which can take an assembly DLL and spit out the swagger all in one command.
Check it out here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli

This can be used by your CI/CD to output the Swagger/OpenAPI document to a file .

Comment: that's interesting - and it might be how I go - but a) we are embedding the UI into the app anyway, because it makes life easier at dev time and more imporantly b) - for what I need it for I actually need to modify the yaml a little bit to conform to certain standards, so it's much easier if I can do that in code

Comment: I've spent a bit of time digging through the Swashbuckle code, the way the CLI works, it technically starts up your web host.  The reason for this appears to be because all of the swagger configuration is nestled inside the hostbuilder magic, I don't think it's able to actually generate the swagger doc without executing that bit.

If you're dead-set on performing manipulations with C#, I'd see if you can harness the logic in the Swashbuckle.Cli: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli/Program.cs to create CLI entry for your app.