# how to "skip" exceptions when running dotnet swagger tofile using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using `dotnet swagger tofile --output [output] [startupassembly] [swaggerdoc]` this command to generate swagger docs, [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) is the repo of the CLI, and it works fine locally.

But when it's in the CI/CD, as far as I know, it needs to start the app, but the app will not start in CI/CD due to some dependencies problems. So the app will throw exceptions inside `Program.Main` when it's run on CI/CD.

my question is, what's the recommended solution there? is there a way to skip exceptions? or even do not start the app? or should I configure what dependency to load in `Main`?

Comment: What kinds of exceptions are you seeing?

Comment: I mean on our build machine, the app just would not run due to some reasons that very hard to solve, so the exception is from our code, but the cli works locally. @AceGambit

Comment: @AceGambit what I am trying to do is that have a different project, trying to resolve the service container from a different app, but not sure what's the best way either.

Comment: Perhaps try initializing your app using a Test Host: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver?view=aspnetcore-7.0
 
That might circumvent some of the dependency issues you're seeing if they're port related or networking related.  From there you could use the swagger library to extract the doc and write it to file yourself.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and think it's insane `dotnet swagger toFile` needs to *run* the application in order to generate the API specification. Is there no way to statically analyze the source or the DLL to get this information without running the app?

Comment: @guyyst I did not find a good solution, I ended up having a different project and building the same container as my asp.net app and generate doc using that project.